# Should I update this questions with OP comments?

Tags: support

I'm trying to explain to [this new user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3588565/user3588565) that adds info to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775063/capture-imei-number-for-tablet-using-android-code?noredirect=1#comment49604985_30775063):

My comments:

> which error you get? –  Jordi Castilla 1 hour ago

and

> edit your question, don't post the stacktrace as a comment... :) –  Jordi Castilla 34 mins ago

and

> Put all in your question and add oncreate method ;) –  Jordi Castilla 14 mins ago

but he keeps adding code in comments...

**¿Should I update the question to include OP code?**

Comment: You *can* -- but it's not really sustainable. Can't really be sure if the comment handling is stripping out any of their XML elements. Better if the user learns to do it themselves, but if you think they've abandonned the question (common for low-rep users to be "disposable") and you think it's valuable then go ahead.

Comment: @Tanner: not a duplicate of that specific question. Jordi wants to know *if* this should be done.

Answer (score 3):

I can't help thinking that SO could be a better place when we all agree to stop feeding the help vampires.

You answered it, now you are stuck with having to turn this into useful Q+A.  Which does require a snippet and the stack trace.  The OP is thick as a brick, you'll have to do it yourself.  Or delete your answer.

Comment: `now you are stuck` No. Walk away.

Comment: finally OP edited question by himself!!!! :) bad formatted... but edited at least

Comment: "Walk away" is something you do in a forum.  SO is not a forum, there's just no point having to maintain an answer on a bad question for the rest of your natural life.  Either nobody will ever look at again and you wasted your free time or anybody that finds it later will express their annoyance at having found an unhelpful Q+A by downvoting your post.